# Reshape a pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that has a column with values like below -

```
[[3. , 2., 1.],[3. , 1., 2.]]
```

I am reading this value and passing it to a udf as a pandas Series. Below is how  the values of the series looks like where type of s below is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

```
s.values = [array([array([3. , 2., 1.]),
       array([3. , 1., 2.])], dtype=object)]
```

The shape of this shows as (1,). I want to it be of the shape 1 X 2 X 3, but using the below 2 way to try to do this gives errors as shown below -

```
#gives error - ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (1,2,3)
s.values.reshape(1,2,3)

#gives error - ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,2,3)
s_array = np.array([s.tolist()])
s_array.reshape(1,2,3)
```

***********Added
below is the sample code where I need to reshape. It's not working completely, but executing it will give an idea of the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf

spark = (
    SparkSession
    .builder
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
    .getOrCreate()
    )

l = [['s1',[[3. , 2., 1.],[3. , 1., 2.]]], ['s2',[[4. , 2., 1.],[4. , 1., 2.]]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['name','lst']) 

sparkDF =  spark.createDataFrame(df)

S_TYPE = ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType()))
def test(s):
   s_array = np.array([s.tolist()])
   #s_array.shape = (1, 1, 2)
   #ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2 into shape (1,2,3)
   s_array.reshape(1,2,3)
   return s

test_udf = pandas_udf(test, S_TYPE)

df1 = sparkDF.withColumn("output", test_udf(sparkDF.lst))
```

I think I might have to flatten the values and then reshape. Any ideas how to achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: it is already that, check `np.array([np.array([np.array([3. , 2., 1.]),
       np.array([3. , 1., 2.])])]).shape`

Comment: @YOLO, your expression does not recreate the OP's series or array.

Comment: To reshape to `(1,2,3)` you have to have an array with 6 elements, e.g. a shape of (6,) or (2,3) or something like that.  If the shape is (1,), `reshape` doesn't help.  You have a list or object dtype array containing arrays.  Can you give us code to recreate your `Series` (with all of its nesting)?  Your description is a bit vague.

Comment: Agree with @hpaulj. You can't reshape this series to (1, 2, 3). But otherwise you could simply do: `s = s.to_numpy()` and `s = s.reshape(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Your s.values is a list with one element.  Somehow, can you create a series from s.values[0] ?

Comment: If `s` is a Series`, then it's `to_numpy()` (same as `values`) will be 1d, possibly object dtype with arrays or lists.  If the elements are the same size `np.stack` might work.

Comment: @hpaulj I have edited my original post to add a sample code to give an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with just the pandas part of your code:

```
In [138]: l = [['s1',[[3. , 2., 1.],[3. , 1., 2.]]], ['s2',[[4. , 2., 1.],[4. , 1., 2.]]]]           
In [139]: df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['name','lst'])                                             
In [140]: df                                                                                         
Out[140]: 
  name                                 lst
0   s1  [[3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
1   s2  [[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
```

A Series with 2 elements:

```
In [141]: df['lst']                                                                                  
Out[141]: 
0    [[3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
1    [[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
Name: lst, dtype: object
```

`to_numpy` makes a 2 element object dtype array; one element per element of the Series:

```
In [142]: df['lst'].to_numpy()                                                                       
Out[142]: 
array([list([[3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]]),
       list([[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0, 2.0]])], dtype=object)
In [143]: _.shape                                                                                    
Out[143]: (2,)
```

Or we can make a nested list from the Series:

```
In [144]: df['lst'].to_list()                                                                        
Out[144]: [[[3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]], [[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0, 2.0]]]
```

Making an array from that list is easy (especially if the nesting of the sublists is all the same):

```
In [145]: np.array(df['lst'].to_list())                                                              
Out[145]: 
array([[[3., 2., 1.],
        [3., 1., 2.]],

       [[4., 2., 1.],
        [4., 1., 2.]]])
In [146]: _.shape                                                                                    
Out[146]: (2, 2, 3)
```

The `to_numpy` list, being 1d, can also be `stack`:

```
In [147]: np.stack(df['lst'].to_numpy())                                                             
Out[147]: 
array([[[3., 2., 1.],
        [3., 1., 2.]],

       [[4., 2., 1.],
        [4., 1., 2.]]])
```

`np.stack` is a `concatenate` version that joins the lists (or lists made into arrays) on a new axis.  By default it is a lot like `np.array`; here it is better from 'flattening' the nesting.

Most of this works if `l` contained arrays instead of nested lists.

### other

To makes something closer to your initial `s.values`:

```
In [174]: alist = [np.empty(2, object)]                                                              
In [175]: alist[0][:] = [np.array([3,2,1]),np.array([3,1,2])]                                        
In [176]: alist                                                                                      
Out[176]: [array([array([3, 2, 1]), array([3, 1, 2])], dtype=object)]
```

`stack` of the list doesn't change much (just makes a (1,2) array):

```
In [177]: np.stack(alist)                                                                            
Out[177]: array([[array([3, 2, 1]), array([3, 1, 2])]], dtype=object)
```

but a `stack` of that one element in the list:

```
In [178]: np.stack(alist[0])                                                                         
Out[178]: 
array([[3, 2, 1],
       [3, 1, 2]])
```

Sometimes if the nesting of lists and arrays in complicated, we have to try several things.  Pay close attention to the distinction between list and array, and to the `len` and/or `shape` at each level.

### edit

Let's look at how the initial shape of an object array affects the 'stack' unpacking.

```
In [278]: df                                                                                         
Out[278]: 
  name                                 lst
0   s1  [[3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
1   s2  [[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
```

If I select a dataframe column by name I get a Series:

```
In [279]: df['lst']                                                                                  
Out[279]: 
0    [[3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
1    [[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
Name: lst, dtype: object
```

The `numpy` rendition is a 1d array:

```
In [280]: df['lst'].to_numpy()                                                                       
Out[280]: 
array([list([array([3., 2., 1.]), array([3., 1., 2.])]),
       array([[4., 2., 1.],
       [4., 1., 2.]])], dtype=object)
In [281]: _.shape                                                                                    
Out[281]: (2,)
```

If instead I select a column by list, I get a dataframe:

```
In [282]: df[['lst']]                                                                                
Out[282]: 
                                  lst
0  [[3.0, 2.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
1  [[4.0, 2.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0, 2.0]]
```

This `numpy` is 2d:

```
In [283]: df[['lst']].to_numpy()                                                                     
Out[283]: 
array([[list([array([3., 2., 1.]), array([3., 1., 2.])])],
       [array([[4., 2., 1.],
       [4., 1., 2.]])]], dtype=object)
In [284]: _.shape                                                                                    
Out[284]: (2, 1)
```

`stack` of the 1d array unpacks it and creates a 3d array - one dimension from the outer array, and two from the inner ones:

```
In [285]: np.stack(_280)                                                                             
Out[285]: 
array([[[3., 2., 1.],
        [3., 1., 2.]],

       [[4., 2., 1.],
        [4., 1., 2.]]])
```

but stack of the 2d doesn't change anything:

```
In [286]: np.stack(_283)                                                                             
Out[286]: 
array([[list([array([3., 2., 1.]), array([3., 1., 2.])])],
       [array([[4., 2., 1.],
       [4., 1., 2.]])]], dtype=object)
```

We have to first make it 1d, either with ravel, reshape, or indexing:

```
In [287]: np.stack(_283.ravel())                                                                     
Out[287]: 
array([[[3., 2., 1.],
        [3., 1., 2.]],

       [[4., 2., 1.],
        [4., 1., 2.]]])
```

I haven't followed your code in enough detail to say exactly what's going on, but hopefully this gives you an idea of what to watch out for.  You need a clear idea of the shape and dtype of an array, and same for any nested arrays.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for this. The np.stack with first element of list was 3d - with shape 1,2,3. Is there a way I can get all the elements, so in the example above the final shape becomes 2,2,3? You did get that using np.array(df['lst'].to_list()), but can we somehow achieve that in the final example where you have np.stack(alist[0]) ?

Comment: I tried np.stack([alist[i] for i in range(0,1)]), but that gave a shape of 2,2 which cannot be reshaped to 2,2,3. With the first element alone (your last code block), the shape was 2,3 which could be reshaped to 1,2,3. I tried using vstack also.

Comment: I added an edit that illustrates how the shape of the outer array affects our ability to unpack it with `stack` (or any related `concatenate` functions).

Comment: Thanks so much @hpaulj for such detail. It helped me understand and figure out a solution for. Really appreciate your help!